# Node.js - the difference between inline naked function calls and named function calls

Tags: node.js

I am learning node.js with learnyounode. I am having a problem with JUGGLING ASYNC. The problem is described as follows:

I have a lot of experience with C/C++/C#/python/etc... and so I am used to organizing my code in a certain matter.  I ran into a problem during this exercise which I cannot rationalize.  If the code below is run with getHttp as the function call in the first for loop - the program exits with a reference error on index (about line 27.. in cbk_handleStream).  I did some searching and read up on 'closures' which I thought I was resolving.

After an hour or two - I decided to rewrite using the more 'node.js' style of formatting which is getHttp2... I am almost 100% sure this is syntactically equivalent - but it does NOT error out on the index variable.  In fact it works exactly the way I believe a "closure" should.

I have looked at this over and over and I cannot understand why this should (or why it would be designed) to function different.  named callback functions do work.  I even experimented with bind and found the same problem.

Any ideas or explanations?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Cheers!

```js
var concat = require('concat-stream');
var http = require('http');

// Get the list of URLS passed to the cmd line
var urls = process.argv.slice(2);
var data = [];
var count = 0;

for(var i=0; i<urls.length; i++)
    getHttp(i);


function getHttp(index)
{
    http.get(urls[index], cbk_http);
}

function cbk_http(response)
{
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.pipe( concat(cbk_handleStream) );
}

function cbk_handleStream(buffer)
{
    data[index] = buffer;
    count++;

    if( count == urls.length )
        console.log(data.join('\n'));
}



function getHttp2(index)
{
    http.get(urls[index], function (response) {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.pipe( concat( function (buffer) {
            data[index] = buffer;
            count++;

            if( count == urls.length )
                console.log(data.join('\n'));
        }))
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

On a quick look - `index` is a parameter in `getHttp2`, and is used in `getHttp2`. But in `getHttp` it is a local variable, and it is out of scope in `cbk_handleStream`.

A bit more precise explanation: This is your code:

```
function a() {
  console.log(i);
}

function b(i) {
  a();
}

b(1);
// prints: undefined.
```

This defines function `a` which looks up the global variable `i` and prints it. `b` defines a local variable `i`, which only `b` sees; so `i` in `a` is undefined.

```
function b(i) {
  function a() {
    console.log(i);
  }
  a();
}

b(2);
// prints: 2.
```

This code, on the other hand, is different. The `i` in `b` is the same, a local variable. The difference is that `a` is defined within `b`, and closes over all variables that are in scope inside `b`. Thus, `a` will carry a reference to `i` with it. When you read `i` inside `a`, you are not accessing the global variable any more, but the local variable in `b` that `a` closed over (thus, closure).

This even works if you invoke `a` from outside `b`, as long as it was defined in `b`:

```
function b(i) {
  function a() {
    console.log(i);
  }
  return a;
}
var c = b(3);
c();
// prints: 3.
```

In fact, since you say you speak Python, the situation is completely the same:

```
def a():
    print(i)
def b(i):
    a()
b(1)
# NameError: global name 'i' is not defined

def b(i):
    def a():
        print(i)
    a()
b(2)
# prints: 2.

def b(i):
    def a():
        print(i)
    return a
c = b(3)
c()
# prints: 3.
```

The cause of the error is in both cases the same: there is no closure in the first examples, while there is a closure over `i` in second and third ones.

Comment: Interesting..

So then while you can define a callback function elsewhere in the code, and then reference it (like I was doing in the getHttp() flow path.  It ends up being syntactically different because of how the scoping works with nested functions in that if the function is defined elsewhere you lose 'closure'.

Ok - its slightly orthogonal but it makes perfect sense that the difference is purely a scoping issue.